# Why is jquery animation messing up my nav flexbox properties in boostrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the HTML I'm concerned about:

```
<!-- navigation  -->
    <ul class="nav sticky-top flex-row justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

My screen shows the photo below, which I'm not supposed to get based on the bootstrap properties I applied to the nav. So why is this happening? Tbh, the JS fiddle, doesn't show the nav items stacked, like it does on my page. I don't know why.

When I eliminate the Jquery, then all the flexbox properties on the nav work. Why is that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav").delay(5500).slideDown(500);
});
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't reproduce the issue. So there could be something else at play here. If you can't reproduce the issue publicly it's almost impossible to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem, but you could have a getaway.

//css

```
.nav {
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
  opacity:0;
}
```

//jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  
       $(".nav").slideUp();
       setTimeout(function(){ 
         $(".nav").css('opacity',1).slideDown();
       }, 1000);  
    });
```